# how to apply find().sort() to multi-dimentional data in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am totally new to MongoDB, and really enjoying while learning. But right now I'm stacked in the middle. Actually I have data like below: I want to apply some sort operations like sort by marks

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "gender": "m",
  "score": [
    {
      "marks": 86,
      "subject": "Eng",
      "grad": "A"
    },
    {
      "marks": 76,
      "subject": "Computers",
      "grad": "A"
    }
  ],
  "age": 18
},
{
  "_id": 2,
  "gender": "m",
  "score": [
    {
      "marks": 96,
      "subject": "Eng",
      "grad": "A+"
    },
    {
      "marks": 66,
      "subject": "Computers",
      "grad": "B"
    }
  ],
  "age": 18
}
```

Comment: `db.collection.find().sort({"score.marks": -1})` or `db.collection.find()._addSpecial( "$orderby", { "score.marks": -1 } )` or
`db.collection.find( { $query: {}, $orderby: { "score.marks": -1 } } )`. Refer to the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/orderby/) for more details

Comment: if i want only subject and marks, what is the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi in given documents `score` data is nested so you should use [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) for sorting so below ways you can sort by marks

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({"$unwind":"$score"},{"$sort":{"score.marks":-1}})
```

Or

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({"$sort":{"score.marks":-1}})
```

Or as reference with **chridam**

```
 db.collectionName.find().sort({"score.marks": -1}) 
 db.collectionName.find()._addSpecial( "$orderby", { "score.marks": -1 })
 db.collectionName.find( { $query: {}, $orderby: { "score.marks": -1 } } )
```

And if you want to only `subjects` and `marks` used mongo [project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({"$unwind":"$score"},{"$sort":{"score.marks":-1}},
    {"$project":{"marks":"$score.marks","subject":"$score.subject","_id":0}})
```

If any conditions then  [$match](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) use for ex:

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({"$unwind":"$score"},{"$sort":{"score.marks":-1}},{"$match":{"score.subject":"Eng"}},
    {"$project":{"marks":"$score.marks","subject":"$score.subject","_id":0}})
```

Comment: aggregation is overkill for this

Comment: @Michael9 aggregate is one way but I think more suitable way given above chridam

Comment: it's working fine, if i want to return only marks and subject how can i give sort?

Comment: i tried with find() before only but it is returning as i given in my question

Comment: @SettiMahesh stack overflow for only question and answers forum if you want to learn more `mongodb` go through mongodb official website and follow documentation's or try this https://university.mongodb.com/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71492/discussion-between-setti-mahesh-and-yogesh).